# key/value store for 1MB values and more

Tags: c#, redis, large-data, key-value-store

I am using redis as a key/value store. The problem is that I have values larger than 1MB, and it [appears](https://gist.github.com/JonCole/925630df72be1351b21440625ff2671f) that redis is not working well with values larger than 100K (The time it takes to get such values is not proportionally higher than smaller values). It is written that I should separate the big values to chunks.

I feel that I am doing something wrong, maybe redis is not the suitable solution for my use case?

Alternatively, is there any c# package that handles the chunks management for this use case?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Comment: Could you refer to "it is written"?

Comment: Have you experienced the problem or just anticipating it? Build a test case. Also you ask us to recommend something (which is not welcome on this site), but haven't described your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

1. You could try just increasing connection timeouts. The problem is
   waiting while the wire is busy. In Redis, if you issued two commannds at once, it will process them in order. So you will get fast answer to first and slow answer to second. In a competing parallel system, you will start to get both answers simultaneously, so both answers will be slow, but time to first byte will be very small for both. For many systems it is not a problem.
2. if you still want to explore some options, take a look at [Tarantool](https://tarantool.io/en/developers/), [Aerospike](https://www.aerospike.com/products/aerospike-database-platform/).